# setTimeout and animation issue

Tags: jquery, animation, gallery, jquery-animate, settimeout

Please help!
I have a strange issue here.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/8Lzxs/2/)

The issue in this gallery is that if you mouseover/mouseout fast **DURING** the animation
than the gallery goes 'crazy', behaving like the .animate() is fighting with setTimeout.

**AFAIK - you cannot use setInterval here, cause if you return to the gallery from another 'tab' the gallery behave like it's going to compensate all the animations (during the inactivity) - at once.**

Please help me understand this issue and find a fix.

*Thanks in advance!*

The code used for the gall.:

```
var galW = $('#gallery').width(),
    imgN = $('#slider img').length,
    c = 1,   // counter
    timeOut,
    pause = false;

$('#slider').width(galW * imgN);

function auto() {
    if (pause) { return; }                        // if hovered : stop 'timeOut'
    timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
        c++;
        if (c === (imgN + 1)) {
            c = 1;
        }
        $('#slider').animate({left: '-' + galW * (c - 1) + 'px'}, 1200, auto);
    }, 1900);
}
auto();

$('#galcontainer').hover(function() {
    pause = true;
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
}, function() {
    pause = false;
    auto();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/8Lzxs/3/

```
var galW = $('#gallery').width(),
    imgN = $('#slider img').length,
    c = 1,   // counter
    timeOut,
    pause = false;

$('#slider').width(galW * imgN);

function auto() {
    if (pause) { return; }                       
    clearTimeout(timeOut);               // THE (added) FIX !!!!!!!!! //
    timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
        c++;
        if (c === (imgN + 1)) {
            c = 1;
        }
        $('#slider').animate({left: '-' + galW * (c - 1) + 'px'}, 1200, auto);
    }, 1900);
}
auto();

$('#galcontainer').hover(function() {
    pause = true;
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
}, function() {
    pause = false;
    auto();
});
```

Comment: This looks like the answer I was looking for 2 days. +1 Shankar! And a big thanks! May you please explain how you came to this idea? (to clear the `timeOut` before it is called? )

Comment: When the animation is in progress sometimes the mouseout event is not getting triggered so `pause` is not set to false. So in the next mouseoever event since pause is not false it will again set the timeout. I just made sure we clear any previous timeout.

Comment: @roXon - Where is the link I will right away go and answer with explaination :)